# How do I conditionally import modules and add instances of struct to vec!, only when the module (and struct) exists?

Tags: rust

I can't figure out how to do import- and instancing-lines such that they tolerate non-existing files/modules and structs.

I tried making a macro that unwraps into such lines based on what files it finds in the directory, using a crate I found that had promise - `include_optional` - which allows to check for existence of files already at compile-time (since it's a macro).
However, I can't figure out how to use it properly in a macro, neither did I manage to use it without macro using the example at bottom of the docs [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) chapter.

`if cfg!(unix) { "unix" } else if cfg!(windows) { "windows" } else { "unknown" }` **(from the docs)**

vs

`if include_optional::include_bytes_optional!("day1.rs").is_some() { Some(&day01::Day01 {}) } else { None } // assume day1.rs and thus Day01 are non-existent` (my attempt at doing same thing)

My if-statement compiles both cases, including the unreachable code (causing a compilation error), despite how according to the the docs it supposedly doesn't for `cfg!` ("conditional compilation").

Essentially, what I want is something of this form:

```
// Macro to generate code based on how many files/structs has been created
// There are anywhere between 1-25 days
get_days_created!;
/* // Let's assume 11 have been created so far, then the macro should evaluate to this code:
 * mod day1;
 * use day1 as day0#;
 * // ...
 * mod day11;
 * use day11 as day11;
 *
 * // ...
 * fn main() -> Result<(), i32> {
 *     let days : Vec<&dyn Day> = vec![
 *         &day01::Day01 {},
 *         // ...
 *         &day11::Day11 {},
 *     ];
 *     // ...
 * }
*/
```

Comment: It seems like the solution hinges on - if `day1.rs` exists, then include it - but I don't think there's an existing macro that does that. [`include_optional!`](https://docs.rs/include_optional/1.0.1/include_optional/macro.include_optional.html) is close, but it wraps the included file in an `Option` as if the contents were a value (could probably hack something together using it). But I digress; you'd probably have to write a procedural macro to get this behavior.

Comment: Also, this totally seems like an XY problem. If you want a way to manage the advent-of-code problems easier, I encourage you to give this a look: [How should I structure a Rust project for solving small coding challenges?](/q/73738228/2189130)

Comment: @kmdreko There is an include! macro not wrapping in an option, but that hardly makes it easier to check for existence (unstoppable panics, instead of None).
And yeah, last year I used a secondary python script that generated the files from a template-file when told I'm starting a day. Just wanted to avoid that this time, and solve it with macros, cause that's a big Rust thing I want to learn.

Comment: @kmdreko as for the linked question, the answer to that is quite unsatisfactory, sorry. For starters, it requires you to run each problem one by one, which would be up to 25 CLI-commands in AoC. Also have a *lot* of code duplication between each file.
With my current main.rs approach, I can write `cargo run/test [-a|1:25]`, where no parameter only runs highest day existing (`run` to use input from AoC and give answer, `test` to unit-test).

Comment: @kmdreko I posted my own answer to my question. A bit late considering I have been sitting on this a couple of weeks, but I did remember eventually :)

Comment: Hey kudos to you for getting back to this! I was going to post an answer probably pretty similar to your first snippet below, but frankly I forgot about it.

Comment: Related [How can I import modules only if they exist?](/q/74642159/2189130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a [`proc_macro`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html). These function similar to regular macros except they allow you to write a function of actual code they should execute, instead being given (and returning) a '[`TokenStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html)' to parse the given tokens (and, respectively, what tokens the macro should expand to).

To create a proc_macro, the first and most important piece of information you need to know is that you can't do this anywhere. Instead, you need to create a new library, and in its `Cargo.toml` file you need to set `proc-macro = true`. Then you can declare them in its `lib.rs`. An example TOML would look something like this:

```
[package]
name = "some_proc_macro_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
glob = "0.3.0"
regex = "1.7.0"
```

Then you can create your macros in this library as regular functions, with the `#[proc_macro]` attribute/annotation. Here's an example `lib.rs` *with as few dependencies as possible*. **For my exact question**, the input `TokenStream` is irrelevant and can be ignored, and instead you want to generate and return a new one:

```
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use glob::glob;
use regex::Regex;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn import_days(_: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let mut stream = TokenStream::new();

    let re = Regex::new(r".+(\d+)").unwrap();
    for entry in glob("./src/day*.rs").expect("Failed to read pattern") {
        if let Ok(path) = entry {
            let prefix = path.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
            let caps = re.captures(prefix);
            if let Some(caps) = caps {
                let n: u32 = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str().parse().unwrap();
                let day = &format!("{}", prefix);
                let day_padded = &format!("day{:0>2}", n);

                stream.extend(format!("mod {};", day).parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap());
                if n < 10 {
                    stream.extend(format!("use {} as {};", day, day_padded).parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return proc_macro::TokenStream::from(stream);
}
```

The question could be considered answered with this already, but the answer can and should be further expanded on in my opinion. And as such I will do so.

---

##### Some additional explanations and suggestions, beyond the scope of the question

There are however quite a few other crates beside `proc_macro` that can aid you with both parsing the input stream, and building the output one. Of note are the dependencies [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/) and [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/latest/quote/), and to aid them both there's the crate [`proc_macro2`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/latest/proc_macro2/).

###### The syn crate

With `syn` you get helpful types, methods and macros for parsing the input `Tokenstream`. Essentially, with a struct Foo implementing `syn::parse::Parse` and the macro `let foo = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as Foo)` you can much more easily parse it into a custom struct thanks to `syn::parse::ParseStream`. An example would be something like this:

```
use proc_macro2::Ident;
use syn;
use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Foo {
    idents: Vec<Ident>,
}
impl syn::parse::Parse for Foo {
    fn parse(input: syn::parse::ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let mut foo= Foo::default();

        while !input.is_empty() {
            let fn_ident = input.parse::<Ident>()?;
            foo.idents.push(fn_ident);
            // Optional comma: Ok vs Err doesn't matter. Just consume if it exists and ignore failures.
            input.parse::<syn::token::Comma>().ok();
        }
        return Ok(foo);
    }
}
```

Note that the `syn::Result` return-type allows for nice propagation of parsing-errors when using the sugary `?` syntax: `input.parse::<SomeType>()?`

###### The quote crate

With `quote` you get a helpful macro for generating a tokenstream more akin to how `macro_rules` does it. As an argument you write essentially regular code, and tell it to use the value of variables by prefixing with `#`.

Do note that you can't just pass it variables containing strings and expect it to expand into identifiers, as strings resolve to the value `"foo"` (quotes included). ie. `mod "day1";` instead of `mod day1;`. You need to turn them into either:

- a `proce_macro2::Ident`

  - - `syn::Ident::new(foo_str, proc_macro2::Span::call_site())`
- or a `proc_macro2::TokenStream`

  - - `foo_str.parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap()`

The latter also allows to convert longer strings with more than a single Ident, and manages things such as literals etc., making it possible to skip the `quote!` macro entirely and just use this tokenstream directly (as seen in `import_days`).

Here's an example that creates a struct with dynamic name, and implements a specific trait for it:

```
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
// ...
let mut stream = TokenStream::new();
stream.extend(quote!{
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct #day_padded_upper {}
    impl Day for #day_padded_upper {
        #trait_parts
    }
});

return proc_macro::TokenStream::from(stream);
```

---

#### Finally, on how to implement my question

This 'chapter' is a bit redundant, as I essentially answered it with the first two code-snippets (`.toml` and `fn import_days`), and the rest could have been considered an exercise for the reader. However, while the question *is about reading the filesystem at compile-time in a macro to 'dynamically' change its expansion* (sort of), I wrote it in a more general form asking how to achieve a specific result (as old me didn't know macro's could do that). So for completion I'll include this 'chapter' nevertheless.

There is also the fact that the last macro in this 'chapter' - `impl_day` (which wasn't mentioned at all in the question) - serves as a good example of how to achieve two adjacent but important and relevant tasks.

1. Retrieving and using call-site's filename.
2. Parsing the `input TokenStream` using the `syn` dependency as shown above.

In other words: knowing all the above, *this is how you can create macros for importing all targeted files, instantiating structs for all targeted files, as well as to declare + define the struct from current file's name.*

##### Importing all targeted files:

See `import_days` above at the start.

###### Instantiating Vec with structs from all targeted files:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn instantiate_days(_: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let re = Regex::new(r".+(\d+)").unwrap();

    let mut stream = TokenStream::new();

    let mut block  = TokenStream::new();
    for entry in glob("./src/day*.rs").expect("Failed to read pattern") {
        match entry {
            Ok(path) => {
                let prefix = path.file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
                let caps = re.captures(prefix);
                if let Some(caps) = caps {
                    let n: u32 = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str().parse().unwrap();
                    let day_padded = &format!("day{:0>2}", n);
                    let day_padded_upper = &format!("Day{:0>2}", n);
                    let instance = &format!("&{}::{} {{}}", day_padded, day_padded_upper).parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap();
                    block.extend(quote!{
                        v.push( #instance );
                    });
                }

            },
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
    stream.extend(quote!{
        {
            let mut v: Vec<&dyn Day> = Vec::new();
            #block
            v
        }
    });

    return proc_macro::TokenStream::from(stream);
}
```

##### Declaring and defining struct for current file invoking this macro:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct DayParser {
    parts: Vec<Ident>,
}
impl Parse for DayParser {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        let mut day_parser = DayParser::default();

        while !input.is_empty() {
            let fn_ident = input.parse::<Ident>()?;
            // Optional, Ok vs Err doesn't matter. Just consume if it exists.
            input.parse::<syn::token::Comma>().ok();
            day_parser.parts.push(fn_ident);
        }

        return Ok(day_parser);
    }
}

#[proc_macro]
pub fn impl_day(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let mut stream = TokenStream::new();

    let span = Span::call_site();
    let binding = span.source_file().path();
    let file = binding.to_str().unwrap();
    let re = Regex::new(r".*day(\d+).rs").unwrap();
    let caps = re.captures(file);
    if let Some(caps) = caps {
        let n: u32 = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str().parse().unwrap();
        let day_padded_upper = format!("Day{:0>2}", n).parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap();

        let day_parser = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as DayParser);

        let mut trait_parts = TokenStream::new();
        for (k, fn_ident) in day_parser.parts.into_iter().enumerate() {
            let k = k+1;
            let trait_part_ident = format!("part_{}", k).parse::<TokenStream>().unwrap();
            // let trait_part_ident = proc_macro::Ident::new(format!("part_{}", k).as_str(), span);
            trait_parts.extend(quote!{
                fn #trait_part_ident(&self, input: &str) -> Result<String, ()> {
                    return Ok(format!("Part {}: {:?}", #k, #fn_ident(input)));
                }
            });
        }

        stream.extend(quote!{
            #[derive(Debug)]
            pub struct #day_padded_upper {}

            impl Day for #day_padded_upper {
                #trait_parts
            }
        });

    } else {
        // don't generate anything
        let str = format!("Tried to implement Day for a file with malformed name: file = \"{}\" , re = \"{:?}\"", file, re);
        println!("{}", str);
        // compile_error!(str); // can't figure out how to use these
    }

    return proc_macro::TokenStream::from(stream);
}
```